# Ruby cannot load any gem that I install (Ubuntu server)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've got a simple script that uses `sinatra`. Should be simple, right? Apparently not.

The code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
```

That's all there is. And it fails, saying:

```
tekknolagi@eos ~/indexer $ ruby torrent.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- torrent-ruby (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from torrent.rb:2
```

I `gem install`ed it several times over, just to make sure I wasn't going crazy. What could be going wrong and how can I fix it?

Oh, and here's my list of installed gems:

```
tekknolagi@eos ~/indexer $ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rack (1.4.1)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
sinatra (1.3.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
torrent-ruby (0.1.4)
```

Comment: Try to take a look at either `.irbrc` or some other *rc file. Something is weird here. :P

Comment: This will not answer you question straight away. i have got two words for you. RVM and bundler. Dont include each one of your gems that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have done everything right. Many times this custom require error appears when the gem is not installed in the proper path. Try not using the explicit require. Use this instead..:

```
require_relative 'sinatra'
```

Comment: Have a look here [rubygems_faq](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/19) hope it helps!

Comment: Okay so I got RVM working, and I did `rvm 1.9.2 do gem install torrent-ruby` and it installed fine, and now running a script that requires `torrent-ruby` runs into a LoadError. Now what?